# Why doesn't the println and the space in the string work for this code?

Tags: java, string-concatenation, println

MyCode

```
public class DataTypes{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        char ch1;
        ch1 = 'X';
        System.out.print("ch1 contains " + ch1);
        ch1++;
        System.out.println("ch1 contains " + ch1);
    }
}
```

Output

```
ch1 containsXch1 containsY
```

Expected output:

```
ch1 contains X
ch1 contains Y
```

Why is my code not adding space while printing x and y, and the new line character.

Answer (score 0):

```
    char ch1;
    ch1 = 'X';
    System.out.println( "ch1 contains " + ch1 );
    ch1++;
    System.out.println( " ch1 contains " + ch1 );
```

You have missed the `println` in first print statement

Comment: I added it but the answer is still the same

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `System.out.print` use `System.out.println`.

Also use `ch='x'`  instead of `ch="x"` as ch is `char` not `String`

```
public class DataTypes{
   public static void main(String args[]){
       char ch1;
       ch1 = 'X';
       System.out.println("ch1 contains " + ch1);
       ch1++;
       System.out.println("ch1 contains " + ch1);
   }
}
```

Save, compile and run the code to the output

OUTPUT:-

```
ch1 contains X
ch1 contains Y
```